# Trouble with getting reactive variable in R to return a data frame

Tags: r, shiny, data-cleaning

Full disclosure, I'm self taught at this stuff so bear with me.

My goal is to build a Shiny app in R where the user uploads a CSV file with dirty data, presses a button that says "clean", and can download the now clean file. I'd like the experience to be such that the user is notified when processing is complete and the file is ready and a table is displayed of the clean data table available for download.

My problem is that I get neither a table display nor a file suitable for output. Downloadhandler just downloads a blank file. Ideally the download  file would by default save to the same folder that the upload file came from. My guess is that the problem is in how I've written my reactive variable and that it doesn't return the processed data as a data frame. I've tried different variations of defining the reactive variable and the output functions in the server to no luck. Help would be appreciated in trying to figure this out. R code is below along with a dput() output of the csv file available in order to replicate the problems. Thanks!

```
  library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Property Record CSV Cleaner"),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(fileInput("fileInput", "Original CSV", multiple = FALSE, accept = ".csv",
                                       width = '400px', buttonLabel = 'Browse...', placeholder = 'No File Selected'),
                             actionButton('actionButton','Clean'),
                             uiOutput("cleanmessage")),
                mainPanel(downloadButton('downloadData','Output File',class = NULL),
                          verbatimTextOutput('ready'),
                          tableOutput('table')
                )
      )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$fileInput)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    if(input$actionButton == 0) {
      return(NULL)
    }

    #the objective here is to take the input data file, clean it and return
    #the clean file

    {a <- read.csv(input$fileInput)
      a$X1<-NULL
      a$x.11<-NULL
      a$x.14<-NULL
      a$x.16<-NULL

      return(as.character(a))

    }

    }
    )


  #User Notification
  observeEvent(input$actionButton, {
    output$ready <- renderText({'File Ready'})
  })

 #File Output
  output$downloadData <- output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$fileInput, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

  #Table Output
  observeEvent(input$actionButton, {output$table <- 
  {

    renderTable({

      if (is.null(input$fileInput)){
        return(NULL)}

      if(input$actionButton == 0) {
        return(NULL)
      }  

      data()

    })
  }

  }
  )
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

#DPUT OUTPUT

structure(list(X1 = 1:51, x = c("ParcelNumber", "\r\r\n17 024800030110<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n17 024800030110<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n17 024300020207<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n17 024300020207<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n14 009400102101<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n17 022000060184<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n12 203104200840<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n14 014000050411<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n14F000500030494<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n12 228105410973<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n12 216105190190<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n14F0128  LL1316<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n14 013700010832<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n17 025300050466<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n17 018800050011<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n17 018800050037<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n14 010500080056<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n14 010500080056<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n12 281107260045<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n14F0128  LL0177<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n12 194704380290<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n17 024800010229<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n14 011600070757<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n11 035001570889<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n14 012700020536<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n14 012700020510<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n17 018500030024<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n13 009600010213<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n14F0012  LL2131<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n17 018600014555<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n17 0227  LL1315<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n12 194104360108<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n13 003000030210<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n17 006000080599<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n06 033600050312<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n17 017900040021<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n14 009400102028<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n17 022600070369<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n14 009400091106<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n14 014000030066<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n14 011900040807<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n12 215105180698<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n11 048501870154<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n11 077002744634<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n14 009900021496<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n22 346112890091<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n13 016100031615<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n13 0125  LL1200<U+00A0>\r\r\n", "\r\r\n12 263307050244<U+00A0>\r\r\n", 
"\r\r\n09F340001502918<U+00A0>\r\r\n"), x.1 = c("OwnerName", 
"CROSSSTONE MANAGEMENT LLC<U+00A0>", "CROSSSTONE MANAGEMENT LLC<U+00A0>", 
"EDENS & WHITT HOLDINGS LLC<U+00A0>", "EDENS & WHITT HOLDINGS LLC<U+00A0>", 
"CRAKER LATHAN K<U+00A0>", "PLUMER NATALIE L<U+00A0>", "RANGEL PATTY<U+00A0>", 
"COBB TIFFANY<U+00A0>", "EGERTON QUINIESE<U+00A0>", "FALL NDOYE NDEYE SEYNABOU<U+00A0>", 
"BREINER TODD A<U+00A0>", "MONROE LINDA A<U+00A0>", "CHO HOLDINGS LLC<U+00A0>", 
"AUER COLIN & AUER ASHLEY<U+00A0>", "GEORGIA POWER COMPANY TAX DEPT BIN 10120<U+00A0>", 
"GEORGIA POWER COMPANY TAX DEPT BIN 10120<U+00A0>", "METRO ATL HOLDINGS LLC<U+00A0>", 
"METRO ATL HOLDINGS LLC<U+00A0>", "KAHN BLAKE & KAHN BROOKE<U+00A0>", 
"BULLUCK SHELDON MAURICE<U+00A0>", "TIGHE MICHAEL RYAN & TIGHE COURTNEY DANIELLE<U+00A0>", 
"MURRELL SOCIAL SERVICES INC<U+00A0>", "CIVITAS WEST END LLC<U+00A0>", 
"BATBAYAR DELGER & DA SILVA DAMIEN MARQUES<U+00A0>", "SHORT CONSTRUCTION INC<U+00A0>", 
"SHORT CONSTRUCTION INC<U+00A0>", "MAAS DANIEL M & MAAS REBECCA M<U+00A0>", 
"GONZALES ROUGET<U+00A0>", "STIBBINS SHARAN<U+00A0>", "WICKS KENNNETH & PRATT ANDREW W<U+00A0>", 
"HARRIS BRENT D<U+00A0>", "STEWART JAMES C & NELLIE E<U+00A0>", 
"URBAN PROPERTY SOLUTIONS LLC<U+00A0>", "BUCKHEAD BASEBALL INC<U+00A0>", 
"HARTIGAN TIMOTHY J & HARTIGAN SUZANNE S<U+00A0>", "BENECKI LLC<U+00A0>", 
"CRAKER LATHAN K<U+00A0>", "CROSSSTONE MANAGEMENT LLC<U+00A0>", 
"VIGAR INVESTMENTS LLC<U+00A0>", "PALMER MATTHEW & STEPP BONNIE<U+00A0>", 
"FIRST CITY ESTATE INTERNATIONAL LLC<U+00A0>", "SWEITZER ARIELLE NAPP & SWEITZER MATTHEW JAMES<U+00A0>", 
"WILSON CHARLES M & WILSON CATHY HENKEL<U+00A0>", "GIBBONS MARC & HOBBY ANNA L<U+00A0>", 
"STROWBRIDGE DEXTER<U+00A0>", "BRIMER SUSAN H & BRIMER SILVEY E<U+00A0>", 
"RAGLAND CALVIN<U+00A0>", "OWENS SHELTON<U+00A0>", "LEACH ELIZABETH P & LEACH SHANNON M<U+00A0>", 
"ALCENDOR TRILIA<U+00A0>"), x.2 = c("Grantor", "DANIELS ROBERT W.<U+00A0>", 
"DANIELS ROBERT W.<U+00A0>", "SHIVANAND CORPORATION<U+00A0>", 
"SHIVANAND CORPORATION<U+00A0>", "RAYMOND B. GOODFELLOW AND LYNDA T. GOODF<U+00A0>", 
"GREGORY, III HENRY D.<U+00A0>", "LANG LESLEY M<U+00A0>", "PC PROPERTY INVESTMENTS LLC<U+00A0>", 
"CONWAY TENNILLE<U+00A0>", "FLOOD PATRICK<U+00A0>", "JIM ROZE CORP.<U+00A0>", 
"D. R. HORTON, INC., A DELAWARE CORPORATI<U+00A0>", "SOUTHERN STATE INVESTMENTS, LLC<U+00A0>", 
"AUER COLIN<U+00A0>", "ENGLAND LINDA<U+00A0>", "ENGLAND LINDA<U+00A0>", 
"TAN BEE CHU JOANN<U+00A0>", "JACKSON KIMBERLY<U+00A0>", "ROBERT L. CORDES, JR. AND ASHLEY M. CORD<U+00A0>", 
"D. R. HORTON, INC., A DELAWARE CORPORATI<U+00A0>", "JOHNSON V BURL<U+00A0>", 
"BRYANT MARSHALL KEITH<U+00A0>", "BRYANT LENARD A.<U+00A0>", 
"BURNETTE SYLVIA<U+00A0>", "D.M. PENCE, INC.<U+00A0>", "D.M. PENCE, INC.<U+00A0>", 
"MARTONE KELLY<U+00A0>", "FANNIE MAE A/K/A FEDERAL NATIONAL MORTGA<U+00A0>", 
"TURNER TAMMY<U+00A0>", "MARTIN ARLIE R.<U+00A0>", "BROCK BUILT HOMES LLC<U+00A0>", 
"MICHAEL WAYNE STEWART, EXEC. OF ESTATE O<U+00A0>", "SOUTHERN R & R LLC<U+00A0>", 
"STATER TIMOTHY M<U+00A0>", "MOELLER MARK D<U+00A0>", "HIRSH MICHAEL<U+00A0>", 
"RAYMOND B. GOODFELLOW AND LYNDA T. GOODF<U+00A0>", "HAZEL BROWN, BY PATRICE B. GREER, AS HER<U+00A0>", 
"COILE EDWARD J.<U+00A0>", "REESE CONSTRUCTION COMPANY INCORPORATED<U+00A0>", 
"BOYD MARK<U+00A0>", "SCHMIETT CASEY R.<U+00A0>", "FUQUA DEBORAH A.<U+00A0>", 
"DOCKER BRENT L.<U+00A0>", "HOMEBILT, INC.<U+00A0>", "BRIMER SUSAN H<U+00A0>", 
"RAGLAND MARILYN<U+00A0>", "RAMSEY GEORGE<U+00A0>", "LUIS IBARRA AND LISA IBARRA<U+00A0>", 
"BRENDA STEELE AKA BRENDA N. STEELE<U+00A0>"), x.3 = c("Grantee", 
"CROSSSTONE MANAGEMENT LLC<U+00A0>", "CROSSSTONE MANAGEMENT LLC<U+00A0>", 
"EDENS & WHITT HOLDINGS LLC<U+00A0>", "EDENS & WHITT HOLDINGS LLC<U+00A0>", 
"CRAKER LATHAN K<U+00A0>", "PLUMER NATALIE L<U+00A0>", "RANGEL PATTY<U+00A0>", 
"COBB TIFFANY<U+00A0>", "EGERTON QUINIESE<U+00A0>", "FALL NDOYE NDEYE SEYNABOU<U+00A0>", 
"BREINER TODD A<U+00A0>", "MONROE LINDA A<U+00A0>", "CHO HOLDINGS LLC<U+00A0>", 
"AUER COLIN &<U+00A0>", "MARIETTA ROAD I LLC<U+00A0>", "MARIETTA ROAD I LLC<U+00A0>", 
"SOUTHERN STATE INVESTMENTS LLC<U+00A0>", "FIELDS JOSEPH<U+00A0>", 
"KAHN BLAKE &<U+00A0>", "BULLUCK SHELDON MAURICE<U+00A0>", "TIGHE MICHAEL RYAN &<U+00A0>", 
"MURRELL SOCIAL SERVICES INC<U+00A0>", "CIVITAS WEST END LLC<U+00A0>", 
"BATBAYAR DELGER &<U+00A0>", "SHORT CONSTRUCTION INC<U+00A0>", 
"SHORT CONSTRUCTION INC<U+00A0>", "MAAS DANIEL M &<U+00A0>", 
"GONZALES ROUGET<U+00A0>", "STIBBINS SHARAN<U+00A0>", "WICKS KENNNETH &<U+00A0>", 
"HARRIS BRENT D<U+00A0>", "STEWART MICHAEL WAYNE<U+00A0>", "URBAN PROPERTY SOLUTIONS LLC<U+00A0>", 
"BUCKHEAD BASEBALL INC<U+00A0>", "HARTIGAN TIMOTHY J &<U+00A0>", 
"BUCKHEAD INVESTOR GROUP LLC<U+00A0>", "CRAKER LATHAN K<U+00A0>", 
"CROSSSTONE MANAGEMENT LLC<U+00A0>", "PROPERTY REPOSITION LLC<U+00A0>", 
"HD CRAFTSMAN HOMES INC<U+00A0>", "FIRST CITY ESTATE INTERNATIONAL LLC<U+00A0>", 
"SWEITZER ARIELLE NAPP &<U+00A0>", "WILSON CHARLES M<U+00A0>", 
"GIBBONS MARC &<U+00A0>", "STROWBRIDGE DEXTER<U+00A0>", "BRIMER SUSAN H &<U+00A0>", 
"RAGLAND CALVIN<U+00A0>", "OWENS SHELTON<U+00A0>", "LEACH ELIZABETH P &<U+00A0>", 
"ALCENDOR TRILIA<U+00A0>"), x.4 = c("Zoning", "R4A-<U+00A0>", 
"R4A-<U+00A0>", "I2-<U+00A0>", "I2-<U+00A0>", "R1-<U+00A0>", 
"R4-<U+00A0>", "R4-<U+00A0>", "R5-<U+00A0>", "R4-<U+00A0>", "R3C-<U+00A0>", 
"I1-<U+00A0>", "AG1-<U+00A0>", "R4-<U+00A0>", "R5-<U+00A0>", 
"I2-<U+00A0>", "I1-<U+00A0>", "R4-<U+00A0>", "R4-<U+00A0>", "CUPC-<U+00A0>", 
"CUP-<U+00A0>", "R5-<U+00A0>", "R5-<U+00A0>", "R5-<U+00A0>", 
"CUP-<U+00A0>", "RSF-<U+00A0>", "RSF-<U+00A0>", "R4-<U+00A0>", 
"R3-<U+00A0>", "TR-<U+00A0>", "RG2-<U+00A0>", "PDMU-<U+00A0>", 
"R5-<U+00A0>", "R3-<U+00A0>", "R4-<U+00A0>", "R3AC-<U+00A0>", 
"R2-<U+00A0>", "R1-<U+00A0>", "R5-<U+00A0>", "R1-<U+00A0>", "R5-<U+00A0>", 
"R5-<U+00A0>", "R3-<U+00A0>", "CUP-<U+00A0>", "CUP-<U+00A0>", 
"R1-<U+00A0>", "R1C-<U+00A0>", "R4-<U+00A0>", "TRCOND-<U+00A0>", 
"R2C-<U+00A0>", "SUBC-<U+00A0>"), x.5 = c("PropertyClass", "R3<U+00A0>", 
"R3<U+00A0>", "C3<U+00A0>", "C3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", 
"R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "C3<U+00A0>", 
"R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "U3<U+00A0>", "U3<U+00A0>", 
"R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", 
"R3<U+00A0>", "C3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "E3<U+00A0>", "E3<U+00A0>", 
"R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", 
"R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R4<U+00A0>", "R4<U+00A0>", 
"R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", 
"R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", 
"R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>", "R3<U+00A0>"), x.6 = c("District", 
"05V<U+00A0>", "05V<U+00A0>", "05V<U+00A0>", "05V<U+00A0>", "30<U+00A0>", 
"05<U+00A0>", "45<U+00A0>", "05<U+00A0>", "05<U+00A0>", "45<U+00A0>", 
"45<U+00A0>", "55<U+00A0>", "05<U+00A0>", "05<U+00A0>", "05T<U+00A0>", 
"05T<U+00A0>", "05<U+00A0>", "05<U+00A0>", "45<U+00A0>", "55<U+00A0>", 
"45<U+00A0>", "05V<U+00A0>", "05<U+00A0>", "10<U+00A0>", "30<U+00A0>", 
"30<U+00A0>", "05<U+00A0>", "55<U+00A0>", "55<U+00A0>", "05<U+00A0>", 
"05V<U+00A0>", "45<U+00A0>", "15<U+00A0>", "05<U+00A0>", "59<U+00A0>", 
"05<U+00A0>", "30<U+00A0>", "05V<U+00A0>", "30<U+00A0>", "05<U+00A0>", 
"05<U+00A0>", "45<U+00A0>", "57<U+00A0>", "57<U+00A0>", "30<U+00A0>", 
"45<U+00A0>", "55<U+00A0>", "55<U+00A0>", "45<U+00A0>", "55<U+00A0>"
), x.7 = c("SaleDate", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", 
"2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>", "2017-01-31<U+00A0>"
), x.8 = c("SalePrice", "<U+00A0>", "$       19,000<U+00A0>", 
"<U+00A0>", "$    1,100,000<U+00A0>", "$      124,900<U+00A0>", 
"<U+00A0>", "$       93,828<U+00A0>", "$      195,000<U+00A0>", 
"$       95,000<U+00A0>", "$      228,000<U+00A0>", "$       99,000<U+00A0>", 
"$      226,642<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", 
"<U+00A0>", "$       48,000<U+00A0>", "$       15,000<U+00A0>", 
"$      380,000<U+00A0>", "$      299,000<U+00A0>", "$      285,000<U+00A0>", 
"<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "$      519,900<U+00A0>", "$       56,000<U+00A0>", 
"$       56,000<U+00A0>", "$      635,000<U+00A0>", "$       46,100<U+00A0>", 
"$      114,000<U+00A0>", "$       74,500<U+00A0>", "$      334,900<U+00A0>", 
"<U+00A0>", "$       32,000<U+00A0>", "$            1<U+00A0>", 
"$    1,100,000<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "$      124,900<U+00A0>", 
"<U+00A0>", "$       30,000<U+00A0>", "$       55,000<U+00A0>", 
"$       20,000<U+00A0>", "$      360,000<U+00A0>", "$      210,000<U+00A0>", 
"$      157,500<U+00A0>", "$      304,400<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", 
"<U+00A0>", "$           10<U+00A0>", "$      262,000<U+00A0>", 
"$      119,900<U+00A0>"), x.9 = c("LivingArea", "975<U+00A0>", 
"975<U+00A0>", "5,476<U+00A0>", "5,476<U+00A0>", "0<U+00A0>", 
"1,256<U+00A0>", "1,000<U+00A0>", "1,128<U+00A0>", "925<U+00A0>", 
"924<U+00A0>", "1,000<U+00A0>", "0<U+00A0>", "815<U+00A0>", "1,271<U+00A0>", 
"0<U+00A0>", "0<U+00A0>", "1,685<U+00A0>", "1,685<U+00A0>", "2,467<U+00A0>", 
"0<U+00A0>", "1,925<U+00A0>", "0<U+00A0>", "17,888<U+00A0>", 
"2,958<U+00A0>", "0<U+00A0>", "0<U+00A0>", "2,013<U+00A0>", "1,552<U+00A0>", 
"1,496<U+00A0>", "525<U+00A0>", "2,144<U+00A0>", "1,848<U+00A0>", 
"1,970<U+00A0>", "0<U+00A0>", "4,598<U+00A0>", "2,832<U+00A0>", 
"1,008<U+00A0>", "773<U+00A0>", "729<U+00A0>", "1,740<U+00A0>", 
"960<U+00A0>", "2,424<U+00A0>", "1,396<U+00A0>", "2,533<U+00A0>", 
"2,615<U+00A0>", "1,841<U+00A0>", "2,378<U+00A0>", "1,550<U+00A0>", 
"1,632<U+00A0>", "1,229<U+00A0>"), x.10 = c("Acres", "0.2181<U+00A0>", 
"0.2181<U+00A0>", "0.8<U+00A0>", "0.8<U+00A0>", "0.06<U+00A0>", 
"0.3202<U+00A0>", "0.023<U+00A0>", "0.1774<U+00A0>", "0.4407<U+00A0>", 
"0.1615<U+00A0>", "0.023<U+00A0>", "0.237<U+00A0>", "0.1377<U+00A0>", 
"0.17<U+00A0>", "0.2066<U+00A0>", "0.2124<U+00A0>", "0.1605<U+00A0>", 
"0.1605<U+00A0>", "0.3079<U+00A0>", "0.2611<U+00A0>", "0.89<U+00A0>", 
"0.5051<U+00A0>", "0.9504<U+00A0>", "0.2803<U+00A0>", "0.11<U+00A0>", 
"0.12<U+00A0>", "0.605<U+00A0>", "0.6221<U+00A0>", "0.02<U+00A0>", 
"0.0121<U+00A0>", "0.12<U+00A0>", "0.6942<U+00A0>", "0.5802<U+00A0>", 
"0.7247<U+00A0>", "2.27<U+00A0>", "2.4<U+00A0>", "0.3116<U+00A0>", 
"0.2412<U+00A0>", "0.1722<U+00A0>", "0.1687<U+00A0>", "0.0785<U+00A0>", 
"0.22<U+00A0>", "0.1683<U+00A0>", "0.2886<U+00A0>", "0.21<U+00A0>", 
"0.8032<U+00A0>", "0.3716<U+00A0>", "0.0568<U+00A0>", "0.3099<U+00A0>", 
"0.4176<U+00A0>"), x.11 = c("SaleQual", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", 
"U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", 
"U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", 
"U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", 
"U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", 
"U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", 
"U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", 
"U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", 
"U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", 
"U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", 
"U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>", "U<U+00A0>"), x.12 = c("YearBuilt", 
"1945<U+00A0>", "1945<U+00A0>", "1985<U+00A0>", "1985<U+00A0>", 
"0<U+00A0>", "1958<U+00A0>", "1980<U+00A0>", "1920<U+00A0>", 
"1950<U+00A0>", "1978<U+00A0>", "1983<U+00A0>", "0<U+00A0>", 
"1950<U+00A0>", "2000<U+00A0>", "0<U+00A0>", "0<U+00A0>", "1918<U+00A0>", 
"1918<U+00A0>", "1980<U+00A0>", "0<U+00A0>", "1993<U+00A0>", 
"0<U+00A0>", "1953<U+00A0>", "1997<U+00A0>", "0<U+00A0>", "0<U+00A0>", 
"1950<U+00A0>", "1970<U+00A0>", "2006<U+00A0>", "1970<U+00A0>", 
"2016<U+00A0>", "1976<U+00A0>", "1988<U+00A0>", "0<U+00A0>", 
"1996<U+00A0>", "1956<U+00A0>", "1935<U+00A0>", "1940<U+00A0>", 
"1950<U+00A0>", "1930<U+00A0>", "1920<U+00A0>", "1996<U+00A0>", 
"1994<U+00A0>", "1998<U+00A0>", "2016<U+00A0>", "1975<U+00A0>", 
"1982<U+00A0>", "2004<U+00A0>", "1980<U+00A0>", "2005<U+00A0>"
), x.13 = c("LocationAddress", "2367 SUMMIT AVE<U+00A0>", "2367 SUMMIT AVE<U+00A0>", 
"2414 MARIETTA BLVD<U+00A0>", "2414 MARIETTA BLVD<U+00A0>", "MAPLE ST<U+00A0>", 
"2438 FERNLEAF CT<U+00A0>", "503 WARM SPRINGS CIR<U+00A0>", "435 HOPKINS ST<U+00A0>", 
"3690 ASBURY LN<U+00A0>", "680 SINGING HILLS CT<U+00A0>", "11205 ALPHARETTA HWY G 3<U+00A0>", 
"2804 BLUESTONE DR<U+00A0>", "1315 ELIZABETH AVE<U+00A0>", "2665 ROSEMARY ST<U+00A0>", 
"BOYD AVE<U+00A0>", "BOYD AVE<U+00A0>", "806 DILL AVE<U+00A0>", 
"806 DILL AVE<U+00A0>", "430 LOFTY LN<U+00A0>", "2684 BLUESTONE DR<U+00A0>", 
"1340 PRIMROSE DR<U+00A0>", "LOTUS AVE<U+00A0>", "1097 WESTVIEW DR<U+00A0>", 
"4140 BRECKENRIDGE CT<U+00A0>", "902 MARGARET ST<U+00A0>", "903 MARGARET ST<U+00A0>", 
"2186 BROOKVIEW DR<U+00A0>", "3425 RAVENSWOODS DR<U+00A0>", "3694 UTOY DR<U+00A0>", 
"1150 COLLIER RD UNIT 17 I<U+00A0>", "1965 BOYD TRACE LN<U+00A0>", 
"690 ROUNSAVILLE RD<U+00A0>", "4465 KENT RD<U+00A0>", "OLD DECATUR RD # R<U+00A0>", 
"90 SADDLEVIEW RUN<U+00A0>", "1095 WEST CONWAY DR<U+00A0>", "3130 OLD JONESBORO RD<U+00A0>", 
"1013 SIMS AVE<U+00A0>", "241 BIRCH ST<U+00A0>", "303 ATWOOD ST<U+00A0>", 
"1003 SPARKS ST<U+00A0>", "1180 ARBOR CREEK DR<U+00A0>", "10745 MORTON CHASE WAY<U+00A0>", 
"5630 OXBOROUGH WAY<U+00A0>", "OAKDALE RD LOT 1<U+00A0>", "730 BROOKFIELD PKWY<U+00A0>", 
"7090 HANIA DR<U+00A0>", "2555 FLAT SHOALS RD 2801<U+00A0>", 
"805 CRAB ORCHARD DR<U+00A0>", "4935 WOLFCREEK VIEW<U+00A0>"), 
    x.14 = c("Neighborhood", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", 
    "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", 
    "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", 
    "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", 
    "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", 
    "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", 
    "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", 
    "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", 
    "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", 
    "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>", 
    "<U+00A0>", "<U+00A0>"), x.15 = c("Sales Validity", "Sale < = 1000<U+00A0>", 
    "Valid Sale<U+00A0>", "Sale < = 1000<U+00A0>", "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", 
    "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", "Sale < = 1000<U+00A0>", 
    "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", 
    "Valid Sale<U+00A0>", "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", 
    "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", "Valid Sale<U+00A0>", 
    "Sale < = 1000<U+00A0>", "Deed of Gift<U+00A0>", "Sale Includes Multiple Parcels<U+00A0>", 
    "Sale Includes Multiple Parcels<U+00A0>", "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", 
    "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", 
    "Valid Sale<U+00A0>", "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", 
    "Deed of Gift<U+00A0>", "Sale < = 1000<U+00A0>", "Valid Sale<U+00A0>", 
    "Sale Includes Multiple Parcels<U+00A0>", "Sale Includes Multiple Parcels<U+00A0>", 
    "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", "2B<U+00A0>", "Valid Sale<U+00A0>", 
    "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", "Valid Sale<U+00A0>", 
    "Sale < = 1000<U+00A0>", "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", 
    "Sale < = 1000<U+00A0>", "Valid Sale<U+00A0>", "Sale < = 1000<U+00A0>", 
    "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", "6F<U+00A0>", "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", 
    "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", 
    "Valid Sale<U+00A0>", "Valid Sale<U+00A0>", "Partial Interest<U+00A0>", 
    "Unvalidated/Deed Stamps<U+00A0>", "Deed of Gift<U+00A0>", 
    "Sale < = 1000<U+00A0>", "Sale < = 1000<U+00A0>", "Valid Sale<U+00A0>", 
    "Valid Sale<U+00A0>"), x.16 = c("Map", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", 
    "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", 
    "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", 
    "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", 
    "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", 
    "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", 
    "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", 
    "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", 
    "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", 
    "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", 
    "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", 
    "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", 
    "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>", "Map<U+00A0>"
    )), .Names = c("X1", "x", "x.1", "x.2", "x.3", "x.4", "x.5", 
"x.6", "x.7", "x.8", "x.9", "x.10", "x.11", "x.12", "x.13", "x.14", 
"x.15", "x.16"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-51L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), x = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.9 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.10 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.11 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.12 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.13 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.14 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.15 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), x.16 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("X1", "x", "x.1", "x.2", "x.3", "x.4", 
"x.5", "x.6", "x.7", "x.8", "x.9", "x.10", "x.11", "x.12", "x.13", 
"x.14", "x.15", "x.16")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Check that the id of the `fileInput` matches the name of the input value you're trying to access.

Comment: Thanks @gregL. I double corrected that mistake and the table returned the filepath along with name, size, and type. The output file is a csv containing that same information so I added a read.csv() function in the reactive variable to read the file in as CSV before processing and now am getting the error message ''file must be a character string or connection."

Comment: Can you edit your post with the updated code?

Comment: Make sure you're actually reading the file path string extracted from that data.frame.